# linux .cshrc file compile error

Tags: linux, bash, csh

in .cshrc file under linux, i have

```
set path=(/usr/local/gams/24.2.2 $path )  #GAMS DIRECTORY (SOCL)
set path=(/usr/local/bin $path)
set path=(/usr/local/cplex/v12.4/cplex/bin/x86-64_sles10_4.1 $path)
```

and when i run command source .cshrc i receive this error

```
-bash: .cshrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .cshrc: line 1: `set path=(/usr/local/gams/24.2.2 $path )  #GAMS DIRECTORY'
```

any help?

I am new to linux, so if i made an obvious mistake asking this question, sorry about that

thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use `csh` : [csh considered harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you were using `bash`, not `csh` family shells.  When you ran command `source .cshrc`, it used `bash` way to process `.cshrc`; `.cshrc` is just the input file, regardless of its file name, so you need to either run `csh` family shells or use `bash` syntax for the instructions in .cshrc. (I wouldn't suggest the later way, as it could be confusing.)  If you would like to stick with `bash`, you should do this in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

`.cshrc` is for the C-shell, not the bash shell. bash uses `.bashrc`.

I don't know about the c-shell, but in the bash shell, you'd set the `PATH` variable like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/gams/24.2.2:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/cplex/v12.4/cplex/bin/x86-64_sles10_4.1:$path"
```

Try `echo $PATH` first to see if any of those paths (particularly `/usr/local/bin`) are already in it.